# Simple "if" statements

Tags: javascript

Recently I've been testing some things and I've stuck on little piece of code. Here's a sketch:

```js
let data = [{
    date: "2018-10-09 18:00",
    temp: "+13"
  },
  {
    date: "2018-10-09 21:00",
    temp: "+12"
  },
  {
    date: "2018-10-10 00:00",
    temp: "+5"
  },
  {
    date: "2018-10-10 15:00",
    temp: "+18"
  },
  {
    date: "2018-10-11 00:00",
    temp: "+4"
  },
  {
    date: "2018-10-11 00:00",
    temp: "+4"
  }
];

let res = [];

function setData(data, day, time, id) {
  let a = {
    day: day,
    time: time,
    temp: data.temp
  }
  res[id].push(a);
}

function parse(data) {
  let day, time, id = -1;

  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    day = data[i].date.split(" ")[0];
    time = data[i].date.split(" ")[1];

    if (id !== 0 && id !== -1) {
      setData(data[i], day, time, id);
    } else {
      id++;
      res[id] = new Array();
      setData(data[i], day, time, id);
    }
  }

}

parse(data);
console.log(res);
```

I need to parse data and sort different days in way like this:

```
res = [[{day: 2018-10-09}, {day: 2018-10-09}], [{day: 2018-10-10}, {day: 2018-10-10}], [{day: 2018-10-11}, {day: 2018-10-11}]]
```

But my code isn't right, and I've done so many attempts and I've failed. Please help me

Comment: Please add sample bad code that you wrote.

Comment: my bad code is shown in snippet (prase, setData functions)

Comment: you want to filter 'res' array ( that you made ) or original 'data' ?

Comment: original data and make it look like res that i've made below the snippet

Comment: Read about the [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) JavaScript object. It is the right why to parse dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to revise your approach, there's no logic that would group the dates in it. Try the following code instead:

```js
let data = [
 {
  date: "2018-10-09 18:00",
  temp: "+13"
 },     
 {
  date: "2018-10-10 00:00",
  temp: "+5"
 },
    {
  date: "2018-10-09 21:00",
  temp: "+12"
 },
 {
  date: "2018-10-10 15:00",
  temp: "+18"
 },
 {
  date: "2018-10-11 00:00",
  temp: "+4"
 },
 {
  date: "2018-10-11 00:00",
  temp: "+4"
 }
];

let res = {};

function setData(data, day, time){
 let a = {
  day: day,
  time: time,
  temp: data.temp
 }
 res[day].push(a);
}

function parse(data) {
 let day, time, output = [];
 
 for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  day = data[i].date.split(" ")[0];
  time = data[i].date.split(" ")[1];
        res[day] = res[day] || [];
  setData(data[i], day, time);      
 }
    let sortedDates = Object.keys(res).sort();
    for (let date of sortedDates) {
         output.push(res[date]);
    } 
    return output;
}

res = parse(data);
console.log(res);
```

If you also want to sort the inner arrays then you can take a look at [sort with compare function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Syntax)

Answer (score 1):

Try this, hope it helps! Cheers

```js
let data = [
 {
  date: "2018-10-09 18:00",
  temp: "+13"
 },
 {
  date: "2018-10-09 21:00",
  temp: "+12"
 },
 {
  date: "2018-10-10 00:00",
  temp: "+5"
 },
 {
  date: "2018-10-10 15:00",
  temp: "+18"
 },
 {
  date: "2018-10-11 00:00",
  temp: "+4"
 },
 {
  date: "2018-10-11 00:00",
  temp: "+4"
 }
];

let res = [];

function setData(data, day, time, id){
 let a = {
  day: day,
  time: time,
  temp: data.temp
 }
 res[id].push(a);
}

function parse(data) {
    let day, time, lastDay, id = 0;
 
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  day = data[i].date.split(" ")[0];
  time = data[i].date.split(" ")[1];
      
        if (i == 0) {

            res.push([]);
            setData(data[i], day, time, id);

        } else {

            lastDay = data[i-1].date.split(" ")[0];
          
            if(day.localeCompare(lastDay) == 0) {
                // Same day

                setData(data[i], day, time, id);

            } else {
                // Another day
            
                id++;
                res.push([]);
                setData(data[i], day, time, id);
            }
         }
    }

}

parse(data);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different approach by using a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

```js
var data = [{ date: "2018-10-09 18:00", temp: "+13" }, { date: "2018-10-09 21:00", temp: "+12" }, { date: "2018-10-10 00:00", temp: "+5" }, { date: "2018-10-10 15:00", temp: "+18" }, { date: "2018-10-11 00:00", temp: "+4" }, { date: "2018-10-11 00:00", temp: "+4" }],
    result = Array.from(
        data
            .reduce(
                (m, { date, temp }) => (
                    ([day, time]) => m.set(day, (m.get(day) || []).concat({ day, time, temp })))
                    (date.split(' ')),
                new Map
            )
            .values(),
        a => a.sort((a, b) => a.time.localeCompare(b.time))
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```